# Fastest way to replace a character in a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I'm interested in finding the FASTEST way to iterate through a list of lists and replace a character in the innermost list. I am generating the list of lists from a CSV file in Python.

Bing Ads API sends me a giant report but any percentage is represented as "20.00%" as opposed to "20.00". This means I can't insert each row as is to my database because "20.00%" doesn't convert to a numeric on SQL Server.

My solution thus far has been to use a list comprehension inside a list comprehension. I wrote a small script to test how fast this runs compared to just getting the list and it's doing ok (about 2x the runtime) but I am curious to know if there is a faster way.

Note: Every record in the report has a rate and therefore a percent. So every
record has to be visited once, and every rate has to be visited once (is that the cause of the 2x slowdown?)

Anyway I would love a faster solution as the size of these reports continue to grow!

```
import time
import csv

def getRecords1():
   with open('report.csv', 'rU',encoding='utf-8-sig') as records:
       reader = csv.reader(records)
       while next(reader)[0]!='GregorianDate': #Skip all lines in header (the last row in header is column headers so the row containing 'GregorianDate' is the last to skip)
           next(reader)
       recordList = list(reader)
   return recordList

def getRecords2():
   with open('report.csv', 'rU',encoding='utf-8-sig') as records:
       reader = csv.reader(records)
       while next(reader)[0]!='GregorianDate': #Skip all lines in header (the last row in header is column headers so the row containing 'GregorianDate' is the last to skip)
           next(reader)
       recordList = list(reader)
   data = [[field.replace('%', '') for field in record] for record in recordList]
   return recordList

def getRecords3():
    data = []
    with open('c:\\Users\\sflynn\\Documents\\Google API Project\\Bing\\uploadBing\\reports\\report.csv', 'rU',encoding='utf-8-sig') as records:
        reader = csv.reader(records)
        while next(reader)[0]!='GregorianDate': #Skip all lines in header (the last row in header is column headers so the row containing 'GregorianDate' is the last to skip)
            next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            row[10] = row[10].replace('%','') 
            data+=[row]
    return data
        
def main():
    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(2000):
        getRecords1()
    t1=time.time()
    print("Get records normally takes " +str(t1-t0))

    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(2000):
        getRecords2()
    t1=time.time()
    print("Using nested list comprehension takes " +str(t1-t0))

    t0=time.time()
    for i in range(2000):
        getRecords3()
    t1=time.time()
    print("Modifying row as it's read takes " +str(t1-t0))



main()
```

Edit: I have added a third function getRecords3() which is the fastest implementation I have seen yet. The output of running the program is as follows:

> Get records normally takes 30.61197066307068
>
> Using nested list comprehension takes 60.81756520271301
>
> Modifying row as it's read takes 43.761850357055664

This means we have taken it down from a 2x slower algorithm to approximately 1.5x slower. Thank you everyone!

Comment: So the data is "rectangular"? (every row has the same number of cells)?

Comment: Seems like you could remove the '%' symbols when you read the line, rather than putting the line in the list of records and then having to iterate over the list again just to remove the '%' symbols.

Comment: It seems that you are replacing every '%' to ''? will it be faster if you use other tools like sed?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes the data is rectangular, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @JimMischel I'm going to give that a shot now and see how that works out.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic I have not heard of sed before but I will give it a Google and check it out! cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially check if the in-place inner-list modification is faster than creating a new list of list using list comprehension.

So, something like

`for field in record:
    for index in range(len(field)):
        range[index] = range[index].replace('%', '')`

We can't really modify the string in-place since strings are immutable.